# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent from a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm still very new to node.js,the array over here consists a list of ids. When I'm sending the response from the forEach loop, I'm getting  `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` I googled it but could not understand properly

```
array.forEach(function(data) {
            db.collection.find({
                _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(data)
            }).toArray(function(err, data1) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                console.log(data1);
                res.send(data1);
            })
        })
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 3):

Because of the loop, your code is calling `res.send` multiple times; you can't do that

`res.send` is an overloaded function that can be called in multiple ways, but any way you use it, it will set headers and send a response. Think of it like an all-in-one, tries-to-be-the-smart-one function.

```
// not actual source code!
// just imagine res.send kinda like this
function send(body, headers, status) {
  res.setHeaders(headers);
  res.statusCode = status;
  res.write(body);
  res.end();
}
```

However, if you want to write a response piecewise, use the `res.write` method instead. When you're done, you must call `res.end`.

```
res.setHeader(myHeaders);
myArray.forEach(
  //...
  res.write(something);
);
res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `res.end()` is called more then once.
The `res.send()`  method is an easy way to respond without need to specify the type of data you are sending **BUT** it can be called only once.
see [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send)

This is how the `res.send()` method ends - [express source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L91)

```
  // respond
  this.end(head ? null : body);
  return this;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code,

```
var index = 0;
var object = [] // empty array
function find(){
    if(array.length -1 >=index){
        var data = array[index] ;
            db.collection.find({
                _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(data)
            }).toArray(function(err, data1) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                console.log(data1);
            object.push(data1);
                //res.send(data1);
             index++;
             find();
            })

    }else{
         res.send(object);
    }
}
```

In your case ,you are sending response data but your array is still processing .so once your response sent ,you cant send it again .

Comment: in the 1st condition you are not sending any response ..hence it will  keep waiting for it

Comment: yes, because once you will get all data ,you can send response back otherwise it will through same error.